# How do I use regex with vQmod?

Tags: php, regex, opencart, vqmod

Once again, I am stuck with some regex and I don't really know where to start.

I am using vQmod to build an OpenCart extension and I want to be able to search all files that have this code:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template')
```

The problem is, the code above has more code in that line in each file. Is there a regex function that lets me search for part of a line of code with vQmod?

here is what I have tried so far:

```
<search position="before" regex="true"><![CDATA[~if \(file_exists\(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get\('config_template'\)~]]></search>
```

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search every catalog controller file (which is where all of these are) you would use

```
<file name="catalog/controller/*/*.php">
```

If you want to do a search for a regex, you use regex="true" and then place your regex in the `CDATA` tags

```
<search position="before|after|replace" regex="true"><![CDATA[~regex-here-including-delimiters~]]></search>
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your answer,  I have updated my question with some example code that isn't quite working.  Peter :)

Comment: @PeterStuart - You should get an error in your error log if it's not matching. Have you checked that no other vQmod has edited the file already in question? I also don't understand why you need a regex for this search?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I got it working. I just wasn't escaping characters properly.  Your answer pointed me in the right direction, so thanks for that :)